# How could I debug requests to a service on Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have the following scenario:

***Pod 1*** receives requests via *http*.
Once ***Pod 1*** receives the request it calls ***Pod 2*** (nginx -> app), which runs at the same k8s cluster.

At a certain point ***Pod 1*** raises several exceptions, saying while it was calling ***Pod 2***, ***Pod 2*** returned *503*. Looking at ***Pod 2*** **(nginx)** logs, it has no *503*, neither has ***Pod 3*** **(app)**. **Pod 2** and **Pod 3** did not restarted or died. (we have one **pod 2** and three **pod 3**) **edited

Do you guys have an idea on how I can debug this scenario?

> Info Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8",
>   GitVersion:"v1.8.1",
>   GitCommit:"f38e43b221d08850172a9a4ea785a86a3ffa3b3a",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-11T23:27:35Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server
>   Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.9",
>   GitCommit:"19fe91923d584c30bd6db5c5a21e9f0d5f742de8",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-19T16:55:06Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

And

> kube-router as the CNI

If a service has a service-ip *10.0.100.200*, for instance, do requests to *10.0.100.200* get logged anywhere?

Thanks,

Comment: Does Svc #2 have multiple replicas?

Comment: Service 2 has only 1 nginx pod that proxies to backend pods (3 of them)

Comment: First you can check if Kube-Dns is doing its job then you can check IPTABLES rules which is made by Kube=Proxy